# Tailwind Container Query not working with padding

Tags: css, tailwind-css, container-queries

I'm attempting to use the container query plugin for Tailwind but my container query is breaking (not generating the class) when I add padding to the parent. When I remove it, all of a sudden it works? Is there something about container queries that I'm missing?

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/AF6cwl41et)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container queries seem to be working. When you adding padding on the container, the `@[360px]:` container query no longer applies because the container content width is now less than `360px`:

```
Padding on one side = 6 = 1.5rem = 24px
      Content width = 360px - (24px × 2) = 312px
```

To evidence that container queries are still working with the padding: https://play.tailwindcss.com/AzP54wWVga